# Do I need a reentry visa to fly from Kaliningrad to St. Petersburg?

Tags: visas, russia, kaliningrad, german-citizens

Suppose I come from Schengen area to Kaliningrad by plane, stay there for a few days, and then take the plane to St. Petersburg. The latter being a flight from Russia to Russia, but it is an international flight.

Will a normal tourist visa do or do I need a double entry visa?

I am traveling with a German passport.

Comment: Kaliningrad to St. Petersburg flight is definitely not an international flight. Train - different story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the 72 hour visa is only available to the EU countries, UK, Switzerland, and Japan.  Which means that the rest of the people will have to enter under the regular tourist visa.

There is also agreements being put in place regarding [multiple-entry visa](http://www.vm.ee/?q=en/node/6473), so I would just apply for that and use it to enter both Kaliningrad and St. Petersburg.

Or you could wait until [EU and Russia hash out the complete procedure on visas](http://www.dw.de/eu-russia-near-a-deal-on-visa-regulations/a-16685862)

Comment: Wow, seems like I should just postpone that idea until the deal is through. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You really should not wait for it. Most optimistic men call the 2015 year, other says that it will be 2017.

Answer (score 4):

Single entry visa will be fine if you will take a direct flight.

Airflot and Russia Airlines offer 6 direct flights per day.